# Show/Hide Widgets in ListView with animation

Tags: flutter, listview, animation, widget

I have ListView of ListTiles and I only want to show first one. Then after button is clicked I want to animate other ListTiles to also appear in ListView(they are empty Containers at beginning).

I tried using AnimatedCrossFade and AnimatedSwitcher between ListTile and empty Container. I also tried some packages but with no luck. Everything I tried does swap Container with ListTile but without animation.

```
ListView.separated(
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index2) => index2 < (!seeAll ? 1 : length)
      ? ListTile(
          //stuff
        )
      : Container(),
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
      seeAll ? Divider() : Container(),
  itemCount: length,
)
```

This will properly swap between ListTile and Container based on value of seeAll which changes on Button press and the first ListTile will always be shown which is desired behaviour. Is there a way to add animation to it. I'm not sure why above mentioned animations didn't work.
P.S.
The Duration was set to enough time for animation to be visible, so that wasn't the issue.

Comment: can this help you?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDybDucp_Fg

Comment: That does seem helpful but I decided not to implement it that way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Visible widget, but I'm not sure about the animation :

```
itemBuilder: (context, index2) => 
       Visible(
           visible : index2 < (!seeAll ? 1 : length)
           child : ListTile(
              //stuff
            )
       )
```

Comment: It properly shows and hides widgets, I only need to animate it. Maybe there is some animation for Visibility state change. I will try

Comment: You can look at all the Animated* widgets https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedWidget-class.html (AnimatedOpacity,AnimatedContainer ...) Maybe you will have to rework you code.

Comment: I tried using AnimatedContainer and AnimatedSwitcher and AnimatedCrossFade with no success. I'm not sure what is causing animations to not show.